# How to change default Null value after joining two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

In MySQL workbench, I want to left join two tables, like the following example:

```
table_a:
---------------------------------------
employee_number   name    e_mail
---------------------------------------
1                 Tom     tom@mail.com
2                 Ali     ali@mail.com
3                 Anna    anna@mail.com
4                 Clay    clay@mail.com
---------------------------------------

table_b:
--------------------------
employee_number   phone
2                 45678964
3                 79845275
--------------------------
```

I create a new table, `table_c` and join the two tables:

```
#create table_c:
CREATE TABLE table_c (
  employye_number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
  e_mail VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
  phone VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ''
);

#perform join of the two tables:
INSERT INTO table_c
SELECT *
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b USING (employee_number);
```

The desired output is as follows. With an empty string (`''`) as the empty value, not `NULL`.

```
table_c:
----------------------------------------------------
employee_number   name    e_mail          phone
----------------------------------------------------
1                 Tom     tom@mail.com
2                 Ali     ali@mail.com    45678964
3                 Anna    anna@mail.com   79845275
4                 Clay    clay@mail.com
---------------------------------------------------
```

However, the phone values of employee 1 and 4 is still `NULL` when I do this in MySQL.

I do not want to just change the output value in a query using `COALESE()`, I want the value to be stored in the table as `''`, not `NULL`.

Does anyone know how to change the NULL values into `''` in `table_c`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
INSERT INTO table_c(employee_number, name, email, phone)
SELECT 
    a.employee_number,
    a.name,
    a.email,
    COALESCE(b.phone, '')
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b USING (employee_number);
```

Notes:

- `COALESCE()` turns `null` values to the value given as second argument (here, you want the empty string)
- you should *really* enumerate the columns that you want to `select` rather than using `select *`
- I would also recommend explicly listing the columns for `insert`

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE()` :

```
COALESCE(phone, '')
```

Note : Always qualify *all* column names while using `INSERT INTO`

```
INSERT INTO table_c (employee_number, name, email, phone)
   SELECT a.employee_number, a.name, a.email, COALESCE(b.phone, '') AS phone
   FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN 
        table_b b 
        USING (employee_number);
```

Comment: I want to update the whole table, not just output the Null values as '' in a query, so this does not work unfortunately.